# How debug ASP.NET Core MVC application using a mobile device?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, visual-studio-2017

I would like to access a debug session from my ASP.NET Core MVC application from another device. For instance, normally the iss is bound to localhost:port. How can I access this by using another network device at 192.169.0.???:port.

In other words... I want to press "F5" to start debug session.  The same way I open a local browser and browse to the ISS localhost, I Would like to open a browser in another device (mobile or pc) in the same network and browse my application by network.

typing the developer machine ip from another machine does not works. By the way, typing the local ip address does not work either. It only works by typing "localhost".

Is that possible using visual studio 2017?

Comment: Press F5 and browse to the IP address of your machine and port IIS (Express) is running at? Make sure you allow incoming traffic on that port in your firewall.

Comment: I already tried this without success.

Comment: Well it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use this [remote debugging approach?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt621540.aspx)  It requires installing something on the remote server for it to work.  You have to use Visual Studio so it requires a computer supporting that.  Your subject says "mobile device", so I wasn't sure what you meant by that.

Comment: I don't know if i make myself clear. I just want to press "F5" to start debug session.  The same way I open a local browser to the ISS host, I Would like to open a browser in another device (mobile or pc) in the same network and browse my application.

Comment: You were clear, and I could be wrong... I think from a debugging perspective the only way to debug anything outside your box was using the link provided...